# Building iOS app (.ipa) with React-Native using Mac Mini 2012

Tags: macos, react-native, ipa

I am evaluating app building for both Android and iOS.

I don't have access to a Mac, but would a 2012 MAC Mini i7 16gb running High Sierra be compatible with the appropriate X-Code version to allow me to compile and build .ipas for iOS device and the app store.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, just make sure it has latest xcode version 9.
Or xcode 8 or above.
Because that will make sure that you can build and upload ipa.